# ORACLE - Consulta tablas con su peso de una base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo una consulta mediante una base de datos oracle, pero no logro listar las tablas de la bd con el tamaño que ocupan. Con que metodo/query podría saber cuanto es el peso de las tablas?

Answer (score 0):

Tomado del sitio de stackoverflow en inglés [Cómo determinar tamaño de tabla en Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012559/how-to-determine-tables-size-in-oracle)

Indican que puedes ejecutar la consulta:

```
SELECT DS.TABLESPACE_NAME, SEGMENT_NAME, ROUND(SUM(DS.BYTES) / (1024 * 1024)) AS MB
  FROM DBA_SEGMENTS DS
  WHERE SEGMENT_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES)
 GROUP BY DS.TABLESPACE_NAME,
       SEGMENT_NAME;
```

Sin embargo no retorna el tamaño tomando en cuenta los indices.

Otra respuesta más abajo indica que si no tienes permisos de DBA puedes ejecutar la consulta que usa la tabla user_segments:

```
select bytes/1024/1024 MB from user_segments where segment_name='Table_name'
```

La respuesta también asocia a otra pregunta del sitio en inglés [Cómo determinar tamaño de tabla en Oracle (Duplicado)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264914/how-do-i-calculate-tables-size-in-oracle) en la que presentan una consulta más completa que toma en cuenta los índices:

```
COLUMN TABLE_NAME FORMAT A32
COLUMN OBJECT_NAME FORMAT A32
COLUMN OWNER FORMAT A10

SELECT
   owner, 
   table_name, 
   TRUNC(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) Meg,
   ROUND( ratio_to_report( sum(bytes) ) over () * 100) Percent
FROM
(SELECT segment_name table_name, owner, bytes
 FROM dba_segments
 WHERE segment_type IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.table_name, i.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_indexes i, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = i.index_name
 AND   s.owner = i.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('LOBSEGMENT', 'LOB PARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.index_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'LOBINDEX')
WHERE owner in UPPER('&owner')
GROUP BY table_name, owner
HAVING SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 > 10  /* Ignore really small tables */
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) desc
;
```

Para ésta última consulta también necesitas permisos de administrador.